Facing Issue in Debouncing concept in react
import React,{useState} from 'react';

const app = () =>{
    const [inputValue,setInputValue] = useState();    

    const handleChange = (e)=>{
        setInputValue(e.target.value);
        console.log(inputValue);
    }

    const debounce =function (fn , d) {
        let timer;
        return function(){
            let context = this,
                args=arguments;
        clearTimeout(timer);
          timer = setTimeout(() =>{
              fn.apply(context,args)
          },d)      
        }
    }
    
    const betterFunction = debounce(handleChange, 300);
    
    return (
    <>
        <input type='text' value={inputValue} onChange={betterFunction}/>
        <div>{inputValue}</div>
    </>
    )
    
}

export default app;

In the above code, I'm unable to make any changes once enter anything in inputfield. Basically updating inputfield stuck. Please help with the reasoning and thanking you in advance.

Does this answer your question? How to debounce a callback in functional component using hooks

Or you can use useDebounce hook of ahooks package.
import { useState } from 'react';
import { useDebounce } from 'ahooks';

function App() {
  const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState<string>();
  const debouncedValue = useDebounce(inputValue, { wait: 500 });

  return (
    <>
      <input
        type="text"
        value={inputValue}
        onChange={(e) => setInputValue(e.target.value)}
      />
      <div>{debouncedValue}</div>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;

stackblitz
